# how to get current location in iPhone app

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

Now my code just open map file but I want current location

.h

```
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>


@interface ViewController : UIViewController<CLLocationManagerDelegate>
{
CLLocationManager *locationManager;
CLLocation *currentLocation;
}
@end
```

.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    locationManager = [CLLocationManager new];
    locationManager.delegate = self;
    locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone;
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
}
#pragma mark CLLocationManager Delegate
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations {
    currentLocation = [locations objectAtIndex:0];
    [locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];
    NSLog(@"Detected Location : %f, %f", currentLocation.coordinate.latitude, currentLocation.coordinate.longitude);
    CLGeocoder *geocoder = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init] ;
    [geocoder reverseGeocodeLocation:currentLocation
                   completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) {
                       if (error){
                           NSLog(@"Geocode failed with error: %@", error);
                           return;
                       }
                       CLPlacemark *placemark = [placemarks objectAtIndex:0];
                       NSLog(@"placemark.ISOcountryCode %@",placemark.ISOcountryCode);

                   }];
}
- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

This code will open me a map view but it's not my current location 
plz help me now I want show my current location in my app

thanks in advance

Comment: You running in device or simulator? and which is the detected location now?

Comment: CoreLocation only works on device!

Answer (score 0):

after getting location, set centre of mapview by

```
[mapView setCenterCoordinate: currentLocation.coordinate animated:YES];
```

Comment: thk for answered but get my current location in Xib or storyboard is possible or not

Answer (score 0):

Set

`mapView.showsUserLocation = YES;`

Answer (score 0):

```
    <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>
```

write following line in appdelegate.m

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:       (NSDictionary *)launchOptions{
if (locationManager == nil)
        locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];

    locationManager.delegate = self;
    [locationManager setDesiredAccuracy:kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation];
    locationManager.distanceFilter = 500; // meters
    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
}
```

and add following method

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation    *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{
CLGeocoder * geoCoder = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init];
[geoCoder reverseGeocodeLocation:newLocation completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error)
 {
     if(placemarks.count)
     {
         NSDictionary *dictionary = [[placemarks objectAtIndex:0] addressDictionary];
         self.strAddress = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [dictionary valueForKey:@"Street"]];
         if (self.strAddress==(id) [NSNull null] || [self.strAddress length]==0 || [self.strAddress isEqualToString:@""])
         {
             self.strAddress = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [dictionary valueForKey:@"Name"]];
         }
         if ([dictionary valueForKey:@"City"]==(id) [NSNull null] || [[dictionary valueForKey:@"City"] length]==0)
         {
             self.strAddress = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@, %@", strAddress, [dictionary valueForKey:@"State"]];
         }
         else if ([dictionary valueForKey:@"State"]==(id) [NSNull null] || [[dictionary valueForKey:@"State"] length]==0)
         {
             NSArray *arr = [dictionary valueForKey:@"FormattedAddressLines"];
             self.strAddress = [arr objectAtIndex:0];
             for (int i=1; i<arr.count; i++)
             {
                 self.strAddress = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@, %@", self.strAddress, [arr objectAtIndex:i]];
             }
         }
         else
         {
             self.strAddress = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@, %@", strAddress, [dictionary valueForKey:@"City"]];
         }
     }
 }];
return;
```

}